# How to programatically & dynamically add CSS & JS while creating wordpress posts in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating posts with the wp_insert_post() function. For certain post categories, I need to dynamically add CSS & JS into the post. Is there any inbuilt function or 3rd party plugins through which I could do that?

I tried wp_enqueue_* functions, using child themes but they apply scripts to all posts irrespective of categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use separate template file for your category. Take a look at [Wordpress templates hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/), you will most likely need to use `category-$slug.php` template. In this template file you will need to use regular `wp_enqueue_xxx` functions to inject JS / CSS that you need for this particular category.

**UPDATE:** To be able to apply additional JS / CSS to **posts that have certain category** instead of category itself you need to use [`wp_get_post_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/) function to retrieve list of categories for your post, then decide if you have required category in the list and if it is so - apply additional assets. It can look something like this:

```
// Assuming that we have ID of current post inside $postId variable
// that can be retrieved e.g from $postId = the_post()->ID
// or from global $post variable
//
// Also assuming that we have $slug variable that contains slug
// of the category, we need to apply additional JS / CSS to
// 
// Example:
// $postId = 123;
// $slug = 'hairstyle'; 

$categories = wp_get_post_categories($postId);
if (is_array($categories) && array_reduce(array_filter(array_map('get_category', $categories), function ($category) {
        /** @var \WP_Term $category */
        return $category->slug;
    }), function ($found, $category) use ($slug) {
        return $found ?: $category === $slug;
    }, false)) {

    // ... Apply additional JS / CSS ...

}
```

Of course this code should reside into template that renders post e.g. in `single.php`

Comment: I have slugs which are dynamically generated from the title. Do I need to create each php file for every post created? Is there a more easier way to do things?

Comment: @mallik1055 it is not a post slug, but a category slug. Alternatively you can use category id, but from my point of view it is less convenient.

Comment: Created a category-hairstyles.php and wrote some code. The code reflects on the page "example.com/hairstyles" but not posts of category "hairstyle". Am I missing something?

Comment: @mallik1055 Sorry, it looks like I misunderstood "For certain post categories..." in your question. I will update answer